# Word for "a similarly minded person"

Tags: single-word-requests

> Alice believes that everyone should own a cat. Bob, the animal expert, has claimed that cats are superior animals and perfect as household pets.
>
> In this sense, Alice and her devotion to cat-owning would find a ______ in Bob.

Sorry for the awkward example -- I'd basically like a word that expresses that Alice and Bob have similar beliefs. You might imagine that they'd get along well if they were to meet each other. My attempt was "companion," but this is still pretty far off from the idea I'm trying to express.

Answer (score 1):

I would say they are a 'kindred soul'.

Comment: Or "kindred spirit".

Answer (score -1):

I use **parallel** or **counterpart** to mean someone of similar thinking.

See [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/parallel)'s definition:

> A person or thing that is similar or analogous to another.

Answer (score -1):

'**Right-Minded**'  or '**Like-minded**' are also useful words in this situation.

Hope this will help!